# Suma de horas totales en cada mes

Tags: sql, date, busqueda-rango-de-fechas

soy algo nuevo en el manejo de lenguaje SQL, necesito sacar un rango de fechas que vaya de mes a mes y el cual tome una sumatoria de las horas trabajas por x persona en ese tiempo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esos son los códigos que he hecho pero ninguno me funciona del todo, al poner un rango mayor al de un día la suma de las horas que en este caso seria "duracion2" es un valor erróneo, las horas deben ser filtradas por ese rango de fechas y por usuario, agradecería mucho la ayuda.

Comment: El código siempre _como texto, con formato_. No todos pueden ver las imágenes. Además, ¿es MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQL Server, Oracle...? Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: El código debe ir como edición a tu pregunta. Como verás, el código es ilegible en los comentarios.

Comment: `SELECT Sum(duracion2)
FROM hoja1
WHERE finicio Between '01/08/2022' And '31/08/2022' AND usuario=' ';`

`SELECT sum(duracion2) FROM hoja1 WHERE  finicio BETWEEN '01/08/2022' <= '01/09/2022' and usuario=' ' ORDER BY finicio DESC; `

`SELECT duracion2
FROM Hoja1
WHERE finicio and ffinal IN ('01/08/2022', '01/09/2022') and usuario=' ';`

tengo esos tres códigos, estoy empleando las búsquedas en SQL en un access

Comment: De nuevo: el código debe ir _como edición a tu pregunta_, ya que es información relevante. Los comentarios son efímeros. Lo que mencionás de Access, también debés colocarlo entre las etiquetas (y me parece haber visto que escribiste "MySQL" también).